# Node js support for "FFI module"

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Is node 14 or future versions ever going to support the FFI module? I am not able to run "npm install ffi" successfully.

Comment: Supporting the FFI module is not the developers of Node.JS's responsibility. It is the module maintainers' responsiblity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [ffi-napi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffi-napi) which is based on node's [N-API](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html#n_api_n_api)